# 1900 dates keeps changing to 2000 in Excel

Tags: mac, ms-office

In Excel -- for the Mac (Office 2019).  I need to copy info from a csv including dates of birth in the 1900s.  Whenever I copy entries from the original file, the dates change to 2000s.  How do I prevent that from happening.
I've tried changing them manually.  It didn't work.  I tried changing the column to text and it didn't work.
I've hired experts and they haven't helped.
Please could someone help me.  I'm working with seriously ill people and I need to get information to medical professionals urgently now and I need the correct Date of Birth.
Thanks

Comment: And you are using 4 digit years as opposed to 2 digit? Ie 1903 instead of 03?

Comment: Also, if you could shed some light on what you have tried, that would help. What formatting? Formulas? Multiple columns to calculate age? Etc would be helpful. I’m sure we would love to help as this must be adding stress that you certainly don’t need right now. Cheers!

Comment: What does the original data look like? How is it formatted?

Comment: Excel (menu) > Preferences > Edit > Date options at the bottom is the usual cause of this kind of issue